# Sqoop parallel connection to different MySQL databases

Tags: sqoop

Can Sqoop connect in parallel with many different Mysql databases which are in different hosts?

Answer (score 2):

Not at the moment, but there is already SQOOP-394 [1] JIRA to add such support.

Jarcec

Links:
1: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SQOOP-394

Comment: is any other way to connect same time in different databases and collect sql results in hdfs?

Comment: I guess that you can utilize Mapreduce engine by writing your own job to do that.